# What might be the possible cause of mysql error 1064?

Tags: mysql

Please help. It's been hours and still I can't solve this error.

My query is like this:

```
INSERT INTO image (document_id, image_dir, page_number) 
VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\\DRS\\ARTICLES\\IMAGE\\', 1)
```

`document_id` and `image_dir` are VARCHAR and `page_number` is an INT

the error message was:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''D:\DRS\ARTICLES\IMAGE\', 1)' at line 1

I already tried putting ` as column-name delimiter but still to no avail.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.  Are you executing this query from a programming language, such as PHP or Java?

Comment: Please print the exact SQL query string (just before it gets executed), and check it. It seems that your application code is preparing the query in a wrong way.

Comment: I'm Using c# that line above is the raw string before execution. It still have the escape sequences. The resulting query that is converted to literal will look like this: INSERT INTO image (`document_id`, `image_dir`, `page_number`)  VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\DRS\ARTICLES\IMAGE\', 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to doubly escape \ character one for your language and then second for mysql. Try making your query like this,

```
INSERT INTO image (document_id, image_dir, page_number) VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\\\\DRS\\\\ARTICLES\\\\IMAGE\\\\', 1)
```

instead of,

```
INSERT INTO image (document_id, image_dir, page_number) VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\\DRS\\ARTICLES\\IMAGE\\', 1)
```

Here is the explanation.

While inserting from workbench, this query,

```
INSERT INTO image (document_id, image_dir, page_number) VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\\DRS\\ARTICLES\\IMAGE\\', 1)
```

works fine then it means in your c# code, you need to escape two backslashes (\\) and that will become \\\\.

If you only write this query in your c# code,

```
INSERT INTO image (document_id, image_dir, page_number) VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\\DRS\\ARTICLES\\IMAGE\\', 1)
```

Then the actual query that goes to mysql server becomes this,

```
INSERT INTO image (document_id, image_dir, page_number) VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\DRS\ARTICLES\IMAGE\', 1);
```

and this query, even if you try to run from workbench will fail.

In summary, you need to write \\\\ instead of just \\ in c# (or any language like java that requires escaping slashes) to make the query work from code.

Comment: Actually when I try INSERT INTO image (`document_id`, `image_dir`, `page_number`)  VALUES( '2018-002', 'D:\\DRS\\ARTICLES\\IMAGE\\', 1) in workbench it works. Also when I to save on other tables like this INSERT INTO `document` (`document_id`, `date_proposed`, `date_approved`, `document_dir`) VALUES ('2018-002','2018-01-22','2018-01-26','D:\\FROM_REPO\\ARTICLES\\DOCUMENTS\\2018-002.rtf') it also works in my code and in workbench. I'm thinking maybe because of the combination of string and integer in the query but the quotes are taking care of that i think.

Comment: @RickMarcos: Edited answer to include the logical explanation of why you need to double escape backslash character. Hope it helps

Comment: @RickMarcos: If this answer solves your problem then please mark it as accept so when other come looking for an answer for similar post, they can easily find the accepted answer and get benefited.